# Creating an external payable function based on other functions (confusing question/challenge wording)

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to complete an online Solidity bootcamp but I'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure out what this specific question is asking from me exactly. The question is as follows:

**"Write an external, payable function placeBet on the Bet Contract. This function should take a **Game.Teams** choice parameter and return a uint256 representing the payout of the bet.**

**Use the calculatePayout function to determine the payout of the bet. The inputs to this function will be the amount of ether sent to the placeBet function and the score difference determined by the getScoreDifference function."**

Below are the contracts in question that are being used:

```
contract Game {
    int public team1Score;
    int public team2Score;

    enum Teams { Team1, Team2 }

    function addScore(Teams teamNumber) external {
        // TODO: add score to the specified team
        if (teamNumber == Teams.Team1) {
            team1Score += 1;
        } else if (teamNumber == Teams.Team2) {
            team2Score += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And the main question contract:

```
import "./Game.sol";

contract Bet {
    Game public game;
    constructor(address _gameAddress) {
        game = Game(_gameAddress);
    }

    // calculates the payout of a bet based on the score difference between the two teams
    function calculatePayout(uint amount, int scoreDifference) private pure returns(uint) {
        uint abs = uint(scoreDifference > 0 ? scoreDifference : scoreDifference * -1);  
        uint odds = 2 ** abs;
        if(scoreDifference < 0) {
            return amount + amount / odds;
        }
        return amount + amount * odds;
    }

    function getScoreDifference(Game.Teams x) public view returns (int256) {
        if (x == Game.Teams.Team1) {
            return game.team1Score() - game.team2Score();
        } else if (x == Game.Teams.Team2) {
            return game.team2Score() - game.team1Score();
        } return game.team1Score();
    }

    function placeBet(Game.Teams x) external payable returns (uint256) {

    }
}
```

So the question is asking me to **"use the calculatePayout function to determine the payout of the bet. The inputs to this function will be the amount of ether sent to the placeBet function and the score difference determined by the getScoreDifference function."**

I wrote the function name, parameters etc. correctly (I think), but I have no idea what to include in the body, as the question is not worded very well. Any assistance would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would write it according to the question:

```js
    function placeBet(Game.Teams x) external payable returns (uint256) {
        int256 _diff = getScoreDifference(x);
        return calculatePayout(msg.value, _diff);
    }
```

However in a production code it wouldn't make sense cause the user is paying for the bet, but this isn't registered anywhere. But the question doesn't mention writing a complete betting system so I guess it's ok.

Comment: This worked perfectly; and yeah I agree the wording and the actual things the questions ask for are a bit convoluted. Thanks a ton!